# Create one PDF from one view with RazorPDF MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, pdf-generation, razorpdf

I am new using Asp.net MVC 5 in C#.

I am trying to create one PDF from one view but I am not managing.
After some days trying for my own, then i began to read in some forums, but I didn't find (or maybe I didn't understand) how to do it.

I installed, from NuGet, RazorPDF, RazorPDF2, and also RazorPDF for MVC.
I used iTextSharp 5.0.5.0 and then updated to 5.5.8.0.
But in any case, it worked.

I had different errors.
First was this one:

> RazorPDF.Legacy.Text.DocumentException: Helvetica not found as resource

and then:

> Could not load type 'iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlParser' from assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.5.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca'

I read one fantastic article here wrote by Chris Hass. But I don't know how to apply it. So my question is, how to make it work in my precise case?

This is what I have in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Factura(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Venta venta = db.Ventas.Find(id);
    if (venta == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var detalleVenta = from c in db.DetalleVentas where c.VentaID ==   venta.VentaID select c;

    return new RazorPDF.PdfResult(detalleVenta,"Factura");
}
```

And this is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MiContexto.Models.DetalleVenta>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NombreProducto)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cantidad)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descuento)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PrecioSinIva)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Iva)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Precio)
    </th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NombreProducto)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cantidad)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descuento)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrecioSinIva)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Iva)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Precio)
    </td>

</tr>

}

</table>
```

So what should I do to create the pdf from this view?
Do I have to use "RazorPDF" or "RazorPDF for MVC" or maybe another tool in the NuGet?
Is my code wrong or the 'only' problem of what I made is that "It hasn't been updated in two and a half years, it requires an obsolete version of iTextSharp and uses an obsolete HTML parser." as Chris has said?

Comment: Looks like you need https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx  - "Redirecting Assembly Versions".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read what you suggested to me and I have doubts. 1.- Where i have to make these changes?  2.- I am using Visual Studio 2013, so do I have to enable automatic binding redirections or to write it manually? 3.- as an example, if I have this line: <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />, I know that the newVersion should be, in my case, "5.5.8.0" but how to know the oldVersion? Sorry if my questions seems to be 'stupid' or simple...But I am quite new in this and i don't know how to do this...:-( Thanks in advance.

Comment: In you're using ASP.NET, that will be `web.config`. You should do it manually, unless you manage nuget to do it for you. (https://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-1.2). For `oldVersion` you put "everything before" in a form `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.7.0" newVersion="5.6.7.0" />`